# What does "pre-existing" mean in the context of a managed entity instance in a JPA 2.0 persistence context?

Tags: jpa

I believe I may have a fundamental misunderstanding with the JPA notion of a persistence context and how it is used by the [`EntityManager#merge(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) method.

### Background

#### Motivation

I want to be able to rely on a certain behavior of the `merge()` operation that I suddenly realized may not be happening.  Specifically, I want to rely on its hazily implied `UPSERT` capabilities.  For the purposes of this question, I am not interested in cascading behavior or caching of any sort.  Additionally, in this question I am not interested in how one vendor may happen to do things or how another may happen to do things; I am interested in the language and the requirements.

This question is long and restated several times on purpose; I've found not everyone wraps their head around it in the same way, so I wanted to present it in a number of different ways.  Please excuse the verbosity.

#### Specification Citations

The [JPA 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) says in section 7.1:

> A persistence context is a **set of managed entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is a unique entity instance** [emphasis mine]. Within the persistence context, the entity instances and their lifecycle are managed by the entity manager.

(So this paragraph says: consider a set of objects; let's name it the persistence context.  Its members will have their lifecycles managed by an `EntityManager` and will correspond to their matching persistent representations off in database land.  Their `@Id`s, in other words, will match corresponding primary keys in the database.)

Note that this paragraph does *not* say how an object gets into the set (how an entity gets into the persistence context), only what conditions must be true once you *do* have an object in there.  Rules on how things get into the set are laid down elsewhere in the specification.

Finally, for completeness, it seems to be semantically OK to speak of an empty persistence context—it is the persistence context that results after you do `EntityManager#clear()`.

Then section 3.2.7.1 says:

> The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> • If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a **pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity** or a new managed copy X' of X is created.

### Question

**What, exactly, does pre-existing mean, when we speak of pre-existing managed entity instances in a persistence context?**

Or: In a roundabout fashion, I'm really asking about what `clear()` does: does it truly empty the persistence context, or does it empty it **only of objects to which I might currently retain references**?

Or: Suppose my persistence context is empty (I've just called `EntityManager#clear()`).  Are there any "pre-existing managed entity instance[s]" in it at *all*, of *any* identity?  Are *all* database rows sort of intrinsically present in a persistence context—i.e. the `clear()` operation doesn't really mean that the persistence context is truly *empty*, only that you can't get anything out of it without adding something to it?

Or: in its implementation of the `merge()` operation, is an `EntityManager` implementation **obligated** by this paragraph to—at `merge()` time—go attempt to just-in-time look up, instantiate and manage X' so that it is as though the persistence context were *not* empty at the time `merge()` was called, like this:

```
// Assuming a previously empty persistence context (em.clear()).
// Pseudocode follows as though this were part of the
// EntityManager merge() implementation.
//
// Here "pre-existing" means "not there to start with,
// but located just in time and thus snuck into the
// persistence context from disk as though it had been
// there all along".  This would mean that things like
// primary key violations and the like at flush() time would be 
// effectively prohibited by spec.
SomeEntity xPrime = this.find(SomeEntity.class, x.getID());
if (xPrime == null) {
  xPrime = new SomeEntity();
  manage(xPrime);
}
assert isManaged(xPrime); // hypothetical method
copyProperties(x, xPrime);
return xPrime;
```

Is `X'` in this case said to be pre-existing, even though at the time `merge()` was called the persistence context was empty?

Or can, instead, a conformant `EntityManager` simply do:

```
// Assuming a previously empty persistence context.
// Pseudocode follows as though it were part of the
// EntityManager merge() implementation.
//
// Here "pre-existing" means "already in the persistence context",
// which given that we're assuming we started with an empty one,
// means we just do a new instance here.  This scares me but I can't
// see how the spec rules this out.
SomeEntity xPrime = new SomeEntity();
copyProperties(x, xPrime);
manage(xPrime);
assert isManaged(xPrime); // hypothetical method
return xPrime;
```

The justification for this interpretation would be the part of the sentence that says "...or a new managed copy X' of X is created", making me think that the JPA vendor can decide whether it wants to bother to do a `find()` first.  Under this second interpretation, where no `find()` is implicitly attempted, at `flush()` time it seems like you might get a primary key violation—the JPA provider might attempt an `INSERT` where an `UPDATE` should actually happen.

Here is the same question made more concrete:

Suppose my persistence context is empty (I have, say, called `EntityManager#clear()`).

Suppose I have a detached entity in my hand, `X`, with an `@Id`-annotated `long` field that contains the value `6L`.  `EntityManager#contains(x)` returns `false`.

Suppose I have an `x` table in my database with a row in it whose primary key is `6`, and suppose further that my `X` entity is mapped to it.

(To blow my punchline early: can we say that `X'` pre-exists as a managed entity instance at this point?  Does it implicitly "pre-exist" because it can be managed instantly, just-in-time, so it is as though it exists?  Recall that we've just called `em.clear()`.)

Now suppose I call `EntityManager#merge(Object)` on that detached entity (`X`).

According to the specification, "the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity, or a new managed copy X' of X is created".

Is there a "pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity" (`6` in this case) in the persistence context?  Recall that we've just called `em.clear()`.

One interpretation says: No, of course there is not; the persistence context is empty; we `clear()`ed it; there's nothing in it; so the `EntityManager` can just fall back on the second part of the sentence ("...or a new managed copy X' of X is created").

Another says: Yes, there is.  The `EntityManager` is required by the specification in this case to grab my `X`'s identifier, use it to quickly attempt the equivalent of a `find()` operation, which, when executed would silently place `X'` into the persistence context as though it had always been there before effectively beginning the *actual semantics* of the `merge()` operation.

Which interpretation is correct?  I hope the latter.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: With Hibernate at least, your interpretation is correct. And I think it's true for all, because the EM has to fetch all the non-lazy associations anyway. Even if an EM implementation used the other strategy, what would it change?

Comment: Suppose an EM could simply create a new instance and never do a `find()` first.  Wouldn't this object then be necessarily marked as one that would require an `INSERT` at the end of the day, and not an `UPDATE`?

Comment: Also: different interpretations might have impact on which lifecycle listeners get called...?  Not sure.  That's part of why I want to understand the specification's intent here.

Comment: No. This check is done before, whatever the strategy is, based on the value of the version-annotated field or on the value of the ID. No ID/version => transient entity => no find. ID/version present => detached entity => update.

Comment: I apologize; having trouble parsing your last comment.  I know that if I `merge()` a brand new entity that the `EntityManager` is required to detect this.  Obviously it is not required to do a `find()` in this case to locate a "pre-existing managed instance", because it already knows there won't be any.  But if I merge a _detached_ entity—one with an ID and version—where in the spec does it say that a SQL `INSERT` will be avoided in such a case?

Comment: It says that the state is copied to a pre-existing entity. If the entity is pre-existing, why would it do an insert? It alread exists. So oviously doing an insert would be wrong.

Comment: Or let me put it this way: suppose I create a new entity, `X`, and (using my example in my question) hand-set its `@Id` field to `6L` to correspond with the row on disk whose primary key is `6`.  Where in the specification is it spelled out that merging `X` will not result in the JPA provider trying to do an `INSERT` against the database?  To me, this is all tied up with the notion of "pre-existing managed instance", which does not seem clear.  That's what I'm trying to pin down.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: But my point is that "pre-existing" is unclear: pre-existing in the database?  Or in the persistence context (which has just been `clear()`ed in my example, so you would think it would be empty)?  Or...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34107/discussion-between-laird-nelson-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: Have you tried it?  My guess is the latter is what most implementations will do.  I'm almost positive that is what Hibernate does.

Comment: You're talking about a detached entity. A detached entity, by definition, is an entity that exists (or at least, should exist) in the database. Whatever "pre-existing" exactly means, inserting a detached entity doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

while this is not an answer to the question posed here, i wanted to add my 2 cents that is relevant to the context stated

> If X is a **detached entity**, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity **or a new managed copy X' of X is created**.

I have noticed that when entities loaded in JPA from a table that is populated using some ETL job, those entities 'seem' detached in JPA. When I read these entities using their finder methods, they get read alright. But when I want to update one of them, after changing a field value here and there, by invoking the saveEntity or updateEntity methods on the JPA repository, the outcome is a new entity - exact replica - but with different ID, and the changes I made to some of the fields.

The original ID continues to sit pretty refusing to change/update. from this point onward, the new entity (X') will behave well with updates, meaning that X' will accept changes and updates as commanded by the program. The original entity however, continues to refuse updates.

So it looks like it is behaving per the specification by creating "a new managed copy X' of X". But what I don't understand (yet) is why should an **existing entity/row be treated as detached right from get go.**

Here is a link to a more detailed description:
[SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry for Unique key Using Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088480/sqlexceptionhelper-duplicate-entry-for-unique-key-using-spring-data-jpa)